# on the characters of the normal subgroup and its quotient

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, characters

I read character theory recently and thought about the following proposition, but I do not know is this true or false:

> Let $G $ be a finite group such that two distinct primes $ p $ and $ q $ divide the order of $ G $. Also $ G $ has a normal subgroup $ N $ such that $|N|$ is coprime to $ pq $, i.e. $(|N|,pq)= 1$. If $ G/N $ has some irreducible characters of degree $ p $ and $ q $, but has no irreducible character of degree $ pq $, is it true that $  G$ has no irreducible character of degree divisible by $ pq $?

Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: No that's not true. Why would you expect it to be true?

Comment: Since I could not find a counter example.  Of course I am a beginner in character theory. Also maybe since for the orders of elements similar result holds. Thanks for the guidence.